# How to force CTAS to generate a single file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm using HDP 2.5 with hive service. When i create hive table by using below query;

```
create table Sample_table 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
stored as textfile 
AS 
select * 
from sample_table_unique 
where state='AL';
```

Either i can able to create external table with specific location.

My question is when i create table/external table the stored file has been splitted ie. like below wise files has been splitted.

```
/apps/hive/warehouse/sampledb/sample_table:
00000_0,
00001_0,
00002_0,
00003_0,
```

I don't want those splitted file, i want one merged file like 00000_0. I don't know how it happen.Please tell me how do i resolve this issue.

Comment: This is basic concept of HDFS file system ... file will be spited and managed by hdfs ....

Comment: Yes i know. But i want single file. how do i make.

Comment: Why? ..........

Comment: Those data are same for state='AL'.

Comment: Why do you want a single file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement runs a mapper/mapreduce (depends on the select query) job to write data into the target table `sample_table` from the source table `sample_table_unique`.
Based on the number of tasks, the number of files generated may vary. 
To merge them into one, you can set these properties either for the session on permanently in `hive-site.xml`

```
hive> SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
hive> SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
hive> SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=16000000;
hive> SET hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000;
```

In case of `TEZ` execution engine, use

```
hive> SET hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
```

instead of `mapfiles` and `mapredfiles`.

When the average output file size of a job is less than this `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` number, Hive will start an additional map-reduce job to merge the output files into bigger files. 
The values for `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` and `hive.merge.size.per.task` are default ones, change them accordingly to the input size.

Comment: sorry after i can set above settings in hive, still it won't work.Those files are splitted. please tell me how do i resolve.

Comment: Did you try changing the size values? What I have posted are the default. Also what is the size of the `0000*_0` files that are generated?

Comment: 00000_0 : 1.5kb,00001_0:1.6kb,00002_0:0.2kb. At the maximum 1mb only. mostly kb wise files are splitted

Comment: How are you setting these properties and how is the `CREATE` statement executed? Both in the same shell?

Comment: Those settings are set in hive session. TEZ execution engine. Yes i'm sure same shell.

Comment: Try setting `hive.merge.tezfiles=true`.